# how to fetch database records as <div>s without changing fixed <div>s in left and right side?

Tags: php, html, css

layout image:

[image: layout image]

I want to design bootstrap div layout as shown in this picture. I need to have to banner advertisement in the left and right corner. In the middle, I need to have dynamic div s which fetch data from database using PHP. But in the middle when I fetch data as dynamic divs, when number of records increases, the second banner advertisement goes down. How can I solve this?

```
  <div class="col-lg-2" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="card" >

    <img src="img/cement_Ad.jpg" height="500" width="300">
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- 2 --> 

<div class="col-lg-8" style="padding-left: 250px;">


<!-- 4 --> 
<?php


$sql="select * from services ";



$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ?>

    <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
<div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-top: 40px; padding-left: 20px;">

<section>
  <div class="well" >
    <div class="card" >
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/img1.jpg" height="150px" width="120px">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
            <div class="card-block px-3">
              <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $row ['name']; ?></h4>

            <div >
                <label>Email</label>
                <?php echo $row ['email']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>Address</label>
                <?php echo $row ['address']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>District</label>
                <?php echo $row ['district']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>City</label>
                <?php echo $row ['city']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>Service</label>
                <?php echo $row ['service']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>Years of Experience</label>
                <?php echo $row ['years']; ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Details</label>
                <?php echo $row ['details']; ?>
            </div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</div>     
    <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
?>
</div>
  <div class="col-lg-2" style="padding-top: 50px; ">
    <div class="card" >

    <img src="img/pipe_Ad.jpg" height="500" width="300">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**This is the result after I used Mr.E-Azam's answer given below**
[image]

Comment: fetch result from DB with concat div

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam can you please give me an example

Comment: show your code, there may be some looping issue in your php code

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam I added the code the col-lg-8 should load dynamic content

Comment: check my answer if not fine let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Below-

```
 <div class="col-lg-2" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="card" >

    <img src="img/cement_Ad.jpg" height="500" width="300">
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- 2 --> 

<div class="col-lg-8">


<!-- 4 --> 
<?php


$sql="select * from services ";



$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ?>

    <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
<div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-top: 40px;">

<section>
  <div class="well" >
    <div class="card" >
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/img1.jpg" height="150px" width="120px">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
            <div class="card-block px-3">
              <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $row ['name']; ?></h4>

            <div >
                <label>Email</label>
                <?php echo $row ['email']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>Address</label>
                <?php echo $row ['address']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>District</label>
                <?php echo $row ['district']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>City</label>
                <?php echo $row ['city']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>Service</label>
                <?php echo $row ['service']; ?>
            </div>
            <div >
                <label>Years of Experience</label>
                <?php echo $row ['years']; ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Details</label>
                <?php echo $row ['details']; ?>
            </div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
  </div>

    <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
?>

</div> 
  <div class="col-lg-2" style="padding-top: 50px; ">
    <div class="card" >

    <img src="img/pipe_Ad.jpg" height="500" width="300">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. According to the given solution the second banner add does not goes down. But dynamic fetch content shows as given above. please check the screen shot I have attached in the question

Comment: So, in what way do you want to show dynamic content?

Comment: May I know why the second row of the div has gone to the right corner instead of coming into the left corner.I just want to solve that,

Comment: I solved my problem with your help.Thank you in advance

Comment: If you use same height data in middle div it comes on left corner automatically...

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem just by changing **col-lg** sizes. The answer is given below

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="col-lg-2" >
    <div class="card" >

    <img src="img/cement_Ad.jpg" height="500" width="300">
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="col-lg-8">

        <?php
        $sql="select * from services ";
        $result = $con->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        ?>

        <?php
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <section>
            <div class="well" >
                <div class="card" >
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img src="img/img1.jpg" height="150px" width="120px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 px-3">
                            <div class="card-block px-3">
                            <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $row ['name']; ?></h4>
                            <div >
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <?php echo $row ['email']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <?php echo $row ['address']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <label>District</label>
                                <?php echo $row ['district']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <label>City</label>
                                <?php echo $row ['city']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <label>Service</label>
                                <?php echo $row ['service']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div >
                                <label>Years of Experience</label>
                                <?php echo $row ['years']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Details</label>
                                <?php echo $row ['details']; ?>
                            </div>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
?>

</div> 
  <div class="col-lg-2" >
    <div class="card" >

    <img src="img/pipe_Ad.jpg" height="500" width="300">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```